# eko/gocache Implementing StoreInterface

Tags: go, caching, interface

Using [eko/gocache](https://github.com/eko/gocache), the docs suggest that the dev can use a custom store by implementing the [StoreInterface](https://github.com/eko/gocache#write-your-own-custom-store). I'm working on a custom cache to use as part of the library's chain cache but one sticking point is the `Set`.  Here is its definition:

```
Set(ctx context.Context, key any, value any, options ...Option) error
```

`Option` is a function that takes and configures an `Options` object, both from the library package.  here is how the library passes it to my cache's setter: [github](https://github.com/eko/gocache/blob/v3.1.1/cache/chain.go#L78)

Within the library's cache implementations, the configured `Options` object is then read to discern, for example, the expiration date of the cache entry: [example](https://github.com/eko/gocache/blob/v3.1.1/store/go_cache.go#L71)

The issue I face is that Options ([declared here](https://github.com/eko/gocache/blob/v3.1.1/store/options.go#L10)) makes all its properties private, so when I implement my own `Set()`, I have no way to read it to figure out when the cached entry should expire.

How is the custom StoreInterface implementation supposed to figure out the caching options used?

Comment: Turns out someone else had the same issue a few weeks earlier.  A PR was merged to fix this so the fix is in master branch, but the change is not yet part of any release tag. https://github.com/eko/gocache/pull/181

Answer (score 0):

The private properties were made public as part of version 4 of the library.  I had to upgrade to the next major version to resolve my issue.